# Save specific combinations out of a list on PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

This is kind of such a specific question that I don't know where to start despite googling so I came here for advice.

Let's say on my page I have three sliders, one has three different color options for a square. The second has three different color options for a circle, and the third has three different color options for say, a triangle. And then a submit button.

How would I go about making it possible for the user to select a color of each and then submit, so it will save the specific combination to the backend? Any advice on how this would be done?

Comment: Have you tried anything? do you have the slider working?

Answer (score 2):

You have to name all your inputs and they values will be sended ehwn you submit the form.

Example:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" name="square">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" name="circle">
    <input type="range"  min="1" max="100" value="50" name="triangle">
    <input type="submit" value="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a form in HTML with all the inputs format and then send the information of each input to your specific URL

```
<form action="../doStuff.php" method="post">

    <input type="range"  min="1" max="3" value="1" name="square">
    <input type="range"  min="1" max="3" value="1" name="circle">
    <input type="range"  min="1" max="3" value="1" name="triangle">
    <input type="submit" value="Send Information">

</form>
```

Each input lets you choose a number from 1 to 3. The rest you can define it with javascript